Strauss introduction to PDE: Exercises 2.3.7
Let $k,l$ be two positive real numbers. Suppose smooth $u,v:[0,l]\times [0,\infty)$ satisfy
\begin{align}
u_t-ku_{xx}\leq v_t-kv_{xx}\text{ for all }(x,t)\in (0,l)\times (0,\infty)
\end{align}
and suppose
\begin{align}
u\leq v\text{ on the boundary }\{(x,t):x=0\text{ or }x=l\text{ or }t=0\}
\end{align}
Prove that
\begin{align}
u\leq v\text{ on the whole domain }\{(x,t):x\in[0,l]\text{ and }t\in [0,\infty )\}
\end{align}

Context and Attempt
I have read through the body of 2.3 and solved all the exercises before this one. Yet, this question still confuses me. After some attempts, I think applying the maximum principle or energy method on $v-u$ is useless. (these methods seem to only apply to the homogeneous case). A search on the Internet gave me this solution, whose end of part (a) make no sense to me. Thanks for helps in all forms in advance.

I'm editing my answer because I realize now that your issue probably stemmed from the fact that we're applying the minimum principle in the case when we have $w_t -kw_{xx} \geq 0$ instead of $=0$, as you said in your comment about homogeneity. We can do this due to the Weak Minimum Principle for second order parabolic operators, which is stated as Corollary 2 in these notes. Theorem 8 in Section 7.1.4 of Evans Partial Differential Equations 2nd ed. also provides a proof, although it is in a more abstract environment.
